# Header not being updated when using session in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session-storage

I'm using sessionStorage to store my login response data such as `token` & `userId`. The problem I'm having is that my header does not re-render at all after I redirect to my home page.

Here is my Header state & `componentWillMount` function:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isUserLogged: false,
            user: {
                id: 0,
                name: '',
                type: 'member'
            }
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        if ((typeof sessionStorage === 'undefined') || (sessionStorage == null)) {

        } else {
            let login = sessionStorage.getItem("isUserLogged");
            let userId = sessionStorage.getItem("id");
            let userToken = sessionStorage.getItem("token");
            this.setState({isUserLogged: login});
            this.setState({id: userId});
            this.setState({token: userToken});
            console.log(login + '' + userId + '' + userToken); //isUserLogged = true
        }
     console.log(this.state.isUserLogged); //isUserLogged = false
    }
```

My `loginSuccess` function:

```
export function loginSuccess(data) {
            sessionStorage.setItem("token", data.id);
            sessionStorage.setItem("id", data.userId);
            sessionStorage.setItem("isUserLogged", true);
            browserHistory.push('/');
}
```

The logging in my `componentWillMount` works fine but I'm receiving the error `Uncaught Error: Minified React error #105`.

I tried changing to `componentWillUpdate` or `shouldComponentUpdate`. The error disappeared but I don't think I should use this especially when the user is logged in by default in another tab.

TLDR: Header not re-rendering & I'm using componentWillMount. Any solution?

Edit: I've noticed the the state isn't changed right away when I log my state after the `if-else` statement. Its probably because `componentWillMount` has to finish running then only the state will be updated. In the docs, it mentions that `setState()` is a pending state transition. Hope anyone can give an answer to this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the expanded error: 
  "105": "%s(...): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.".

Comment: With that error, it feels like the problem is somewhere else in your component.

Comment: componentWillMount is done before any rendering. and yes setState is asynchronous, whenever you set the state it gets added to a list of changes and these get executed sequentially and asynchronously.

Comment: @Jayce444 so what is your suggestion on how I should fix my problem?

Comment: `componentWillMount` will be invoked only once. You need [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)